# Permissions for two schemas in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema

I have two schemas MONITORING and MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.
I am trying to create a table to which both schemas have access.
I am running the script as MONITORING_CONFIGURATION, but it is not completely ruled out that it runs as MONITORING. Can I simply ignore the error that i am getting on GRANT and get permissions because I created the table as MONITORING_CONFIGURATION while still achieving the goal of a table to which both schemas have access? The error is `SQL-Fehler: ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
01749. 00000 -  "you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself"`

```
  CREATE TABLE "MONITORING"."WEB_SERVICE_STATUS" 
   (    "WEB_SERVICE_STATUS_ID" NUMBER, 
    "WEB_SERVICE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" CHAR(1)
   );
  GRANT ALTER, DELETE, INDEX, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, ON COMMIT REFRESH, QUERY REWRITE, DEBUG, FLASHBACK ON "MONITORING"."WEB_SERVICE_STATUS" TO "MONITORING_CONFIGURATION";
```

When I do `select * from "MONITORING"."WEB_SERVICE_STATUS";` it appears I have the `SELECT` permission.

Comment: I think I will split the script into two parts, one to be run by `MONITORING_CONFIGURATION` and the next to be run as `MONITORING`

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the table, and then rerun that exact script as MONITORING. Then you will know you have the correct grants for both users.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help - use PLSQL to add logic around what the current user is then taken the appropriate action via dynamic SQL using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE
   vsql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   IF user = 'MONITORING' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Running as ' || USER || ' - creating table' );
      vsql := 'CREATE TABLE "MONITORING"."WEB_SERVICE_STATUS" 
   (    "WEB_SERVICE_STATUS_ID" NUMBER, 
    "WEB_SERVICE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" CHAR(1)
   )';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Running as ' || USER || ' - issuing grant' );
      vsql := ' GRANT ALTER, DELETE, INDEX, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, ON COMMIT REFRESH, QUERY REWRITE, DEBUG, FLASHBACK ON "MONITORING"."WEB_SERVICE_STATUS" TO "MONITORING_CONFIGURATION"';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql;
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Running as ' || USER || ' - no action taken' );
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful. But I will go at it with a two-script-solution, one running as MONITORING_CONFIGURATION and the other as MONITORING.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve connection between to schema- ?

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK MONITORING_CONFIGURATION
       USING 'MONITORING_CONFIGURATION';
```

Comment: No the schemata run on the same database. But thanks for the suggestion.